# Split dataframe by two repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which describes the status of a person:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3], 
                  'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 23, 11, 12, 13], 
                  'C': ['start', 'running', 'running', 'end', 'running', 'start', 'running', 'resting', 'end']})
```

This dataframe records two trips of the person. I want to split it based on the values of column C, 'start' and 'end'. The other values in column C do not matter.

I could divide the dataframe by the following codes:

```
x=[]
y=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['C'][i]=='start':
        x.append(i)
    elif df['C'][i]=='end':
        y.append(i)

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    new_df = df.iloc[i:j+1,:]
    print(new_df)
```

However, I'm wondering is there any more efficient way to divide it without loop since I have a pretty large dataframe.

Comment: @Datanovice No, I want to divide the dataframe. The dataframe here should be divided into two dataframes. For each one of them, the column C starts with A and ends with C

Comment: @PeiLi What if in column `C` are values in order for example `'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'`. How the dataframe is divided then?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely There has to be a 'C' after 'A' in my data, like start and end.

Comment: is it not making more sense to split based on your original data? so you'll have the data for however many df you'll need without worrying how to do it in a single df

Comment: @PeiLi Are between `'C'` and `'A'` other values? For example `'A', 'B', 'C', 'XXX', 'A', 'B', 'C'` ?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely Yes, it is possible, but I do not need it. I only want the data between the 'A' and 'C' range

Comment: I did some changes to the data to make it is easier to understand

Comment: row 4 is omitted in groups?

Comment: @ansev Yes, you can treat it as error data

Answer (score 2):

I would create a dict using [`GroupBy.__iter__()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html)

**Method 1**

```
start = df['C'].eq('start')
dfs = dict(df.loc[(start.add(df['C'].shift().eq('end')).cumsum()%2).eq(1)]
             .groupby(start.cumsum())
             .__iter__())

#{1:    A  B        C
# 0  1  6    start
# 1  2  7  running
# 2  3  8  running
# 3  4  9      end, 2:    A   B        C
# 5  6  23    start
# 6  7  11  running
# 7  8  12  resting
# 8  3  13      end}
```

**Method 2**

```
start = df['C'].eq('start')
dfs = dict(df.loc[start.where(start)
                       .groupby(df['C'].shift()
                                       .eq('end')
                                       .cumsum())
                       .ffill().notna()]
             .groupby(start.cumsum())
             .__iter__())

#{1:    A  B        C
# 0  1  6    start
# 1  2  7  running
# 2  3  8  running
# 3  4  9      end, 2:    A   B        C
# 5  6  23    start
# 6  7  11  running
# 7  8  12  resting
# 8  3  13      end}
```

**Accessing DataFrame**

```
print(dfs[1])
   A  B        C
0  1  6    start
1  2  7  running
2  3  8  running
3  4  9      end

print(dfs[2])
   A   B        C
5  6  23    start
6  7  11  running
7  8  12  resting
8  3  13      end
```

---

We can use [`groupby.get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html)

```
dfs = (df.loc[start.where(start)
                   .groupby(df['C'].shift()
                                   .eq('end')
                                   .cumsum())
                       .ffill().notna()]
          .groupby(start.cumsum()))
df1=dfs.get_group(1)
df2=dfs.get_group(2) 
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

---

**Details Method 2**

```
start.where(start)
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    1.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
Name: C, dtype: float64

df['C'].shift().eq('end').cumsum()


0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

as you can see `row 4` is within group 1, and when using [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) its value remains `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the starting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3],
                  'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 23, 11, 12, 13],
                  'C': ['start', 'running', 'running', 'end', 'running', 'start', 'running', 'resting', 'end']})
```

Then:

```
for g in df.groupby(df.assign(tmp=(df['C'] == 'start'))['tmp'].cumsum()):
    m = (g[1]['C'] == 'end').shift().fillna(False).cumsum() == 0
    print(g[1][m])
```

Prints:

```
   A  B        C
0  1  6    start
1  2  7  running
2  3  8  running
3  4  9      end
   A   B        C
5  6  23    start
6  7  11  running
7  8  12  resting
8  3  13      end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
idx = zip(df[df['C'] == 'A'].index, df[df['C'] == 'C'].index)
dfs = [df.loc[i:j] for i, j in idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np
df["group"]=df.groupby("C").cumcount()

df.loc[df["C"].ne("start"), "group"]=None

df["group"]=np.where(np.logical_and(df["C"].shift(1).eq("end"), df["C"].ne("start")), -1, df["group"])

df["group"]=df["group"].ffill()


dfs=[df.loc[df["group"].eq(grp)] for grp in df.groupby("group").groups]
```

Outputs:

```py
#dfs[0]
   A   B        C  group
4  5  10  running   -1.0

#dfs[1]
   A  B        C  group
0  1  6    start    0.0
1  2  7  running    0.0
2  3  8  running    0.0
3  4  9      end    0.0

#dfs[2]
   A   B        C  group
5  6  23    start    1.0
6  7  11  running    1.0
7  8  12  resting    1.0
8  3  13      end    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

using `str_extract` | `cumsum` and `groupby` then holding your results in a dictionary.

```
df_dict = {}
counter =0 

for group, data in df.assign(
    g=df["C"].str.extract("(A|C)").bfill().apply(lambda x: x.ne("C")).cumsum()
).groupby("g"):
    counter += 1
    df_dict[counter] = data.drop('g',axis=1)
```

---

```
df_dict[1]
   A  B  C
0  1  6  A
1  2  7  B
2  3  8  D
3  4  9  C


df_dict[2]

   A   B  C
4  5  10  A
5  6  11  B
6  7  12  E
7  8  13  C
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with this line of code :

```
dfs = [ df[start:end+1] 
        for start, end in zip(df.index[df['C'] == 'start'], 
                              df.index[df['C'] == 'end'])]
```

Output:

```
dfs[0]

   A  B        C
0  1  6    start
1  2  7  running
2  3  8  running
3  4  9      end

dfs[1]

   A   B        C
5  6  23    start
6  7  11  running
7  8  12  resting
8  3  13      end
```

Comment: Can this be done when you have essentially a delimiter row in a dataframe. I have a row consisting of 'T', np.nan x 8 between my data which I want to split into a list. Do you have any idea how this can be done?